# Android Studio error with HAMX

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

Currently running some SDK samples so I know the issue does not lie in the code.

When I try to run the Android Emulator I get this error

```
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
emulator: VCPU shutdown request
EAX=e0000011 EBX=00000000 ECX=00000000 EDX=00000000
ESI=00020800 EDI=c0a47000 EBP=00c63003 ESP=00844000
EIP=008b68fb EFL=00010002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 00000000 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0020 00001000 00000067 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     0084e2c0 0000001f
IDT=     00000000 00000000
CR0=e0000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=008e0000 CR4=00000000
DR0=00000000 DR1=00000000 DR2=00000000 DR3=00000000 
DR6=ffff0ff0 DR7=00000400
```

HAMX installer is up to date. Android Studio is also up to date

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have installed `HAXM installer` on your SDK Manager.

[image: Android SDK Manager]

After you download it and make sure you **run** the setup located in:
**{SDK_FOLDER}\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\intelhaxm.exe**

Note: in Android Studio, the command "intelhaxm.exe" has been changed to "intelhaxm-android.exe"

If you get the error **"VT not supported"** during the installation disable Hyper-V on windows features. You can execute this command `dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V`. You will also need "Virtualization Technology" to be enabled on your BIOS
fellows this links [youtube links here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LjQnkIl_D54<br)

[download here Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager](http://www.mediafire.com/download/a8wbilhheaymgad/Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager.rar)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply I will try that. I am running Mac OS also

Comment: In my case, HAXM was already installed on my Mac but I went into `~/Library/Android/sdk/extras/intel/Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager/` and re-installed HAXM by running the .dmg installer again.